# Criptografia no sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, criptografia

Estou precisando guardar alguns dados no SQLite, mas esses dados precisam ser criptografados, e, quando o usuário precisar, descriptografados. Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isso?

Comment: Da uma pesquisada sobre MD5 em SQLite Android

Comment: pesquisei e todos dizem que não é uma boa ideia usar md5

Comment: A [resposta do Rômulo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188729/215) é boa, mas tome muito cuidado com a questão da senha que deriva a chave do banco. Se essa senha não estiver guardada num lugar seguro (ou pior, se ela estiver numa string do código fonte!) então a criptografia não serve pra nada, um atacante que obtivesse uma cópia do banco também obteria uma cópia da senha. Sugiro que elabore um modelo de ameaça (tipo, em que cenários um atacante pode acessar o BD? nesses cenários, a senha ainda está segura?) e planeje a gestão/armazenamento da senha de acordo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o SQLCipher para Android

https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/

SQLCipher usa criptografia AES de 256-bit para criptografar o banco com páginas de 1kb. A biblioteca tem os métodos `getReadableDatabase()` e `getWritableDatabase()` com a exigência de uma senha, a senha em si não é a chave que criptografa e descriptografa o banco, mas que gera a chave a partir desta senha. Sendo assim, tal senha pode ser assegurada num servidor para ser fornecida ao app para que o mesmo possa acessar o banco de dados local.

Explicarei os passos de como usar a biblioteca no Android Studio num projeto novo.

Você pode adicionar o SQLCipher ao aplicativo adicionando-o como uma dependência no Gradle ao adicionar:

```
compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.6@aar'
```

no arquivo `build.gradle`. Lembrando que a versão 3.5.6 é a última versão lançada no momento deste escrito, você pode verificar as versões disponíveis no [repo Maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.zetetic%22%20AND%20a%3A%22android-database-sqlcipher%22).

Ao fazer o *re-sync* e rodar o aplicativo você pode ver que o APK cresceu um pouco de tamanho.

Após isso você já pode criar um banco SQLite para usar, caso não saiba como pode aprender este procedimento diretamente do [treinamento Android da Google sobre bancos de dados](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Definimos uma classe com as informações de tabelas:

```
package com.example.sqlcipher;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public final class FeedReaderContract {
    public FeedReaderContract() {}

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "news";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "news_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
    }
}
```

E definimos uma classe Helper usando o `net.sqlcipher.database` ao invés de `android.database.sqlite`, pois o sqlcipher tem uma implementação própria do SQLite, e sem `onDowngrade()` porque o sqlcipher só suporta Android 2.1 em diante.

```
package com.example.sqlcipher;

import android.content.Context;

import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static FeedReaderDbHelper instance;

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + TEXT_TYPE + "," +
        FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + "," +
        FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE + TEXT_TYPE +
        " )";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME;

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    static public synchronized FeedReaderDbHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new FeedReaderDbHelper(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Daqui em diante usaríamos o Helper para acessar o banco de dados quase da mesma maneira que faríamos com o driver SQLite nativo do Android:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = FeedReaderDbHelper.getInstance(this).getWritableDatabase("somePass");
```

Apenas temos ainda algumas coisas a serem modificadas:

1. Use a biblioteca `net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;`
2. Adicione no método `onCreate` da sua `MainActivity` a linha `SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);` para carregar as dependências do sqlcipher antes de usá-lo (uns 7MB extra no APK)

Uma `MainActivity` de exemplo usando o SQLCipher fica mais ou menos assim:

```
package com.example.sqlcipher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import net.sqlcipher.Cursor;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this); // para carregar as libs
        insertSthToDb(); // para testar a inserção no banco
    }

    private void insertSthToDb() {
        // getInstance com senha
        SQLiteDatabase db = FeedReaderDbHelper.getInstance(this).getWritableDatabase("somePass");

        // Valores a serem adicionados
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID, 1);
        values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, "Easter Bunny has escaped!");
        values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE, "A thrilling story which proves how fragile our hearts are...");

        // Inserção no banco
        db.insert(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        // Lê do banco e escreve o número de linhas registradas no banco
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM '" + FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + "';", null);
        Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Rows count: " + cursor.getCount());
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // Essa linha carrega sem passar a senha correta e gera o erro: file is encrypted or is not a database: create locale table failed
        //db = FeedReaderDbHelper.getInstance(this).getWritableDatabase("");
    }
}
```

Ref.:

- http://lomza.totem-soft.com/tutorial-add-sqlcipher-to-your-android-app/
- https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher
- https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/18/android-database-encryption-using-sqlcipher/

Comment: Poderia mostrar um exemplo? A comunidade não incentiva respostas apenas com links! Obrigado!

Comment: parece que ele é usado pra criptografar, mas não parece que ele serve pra descriptografar

Comment: Não, não @Marceloawq ele não criptografa o banco num processo único, o SQLCipher acessa um banco de dados criptografado substituindo a biblioteca SQLite padrão embutida no Android, assim você a usa de forma similar mas o banco de dados fica sempre criptografado em AES 256-bit